# Students have mentors, who are also students. How do I get the name of students that are mentoring more than 4 people?

Tags: sql

The students table has 4 fields. Student ID, name, location, and mentor ID. The mentor ID points to a student ID. Students can mentor many people, however a person can only have one mentor.

The two methods I have come up with are as follows:

```
SELECT s.Name
FROM Students s
WHERE s.Id IN (SELECT s2.MentorId
               FROM Students s2
               GROUP BY s2.MentorId
               HAVING COUNT(s2.MentorId) > 4)
```

OR

```
SELECT s2.Name
FROM students s
JOIN students s2 ON s2.Id = s.MentorId
GROUP BY s2.Name
HAVING COUNT(s2.Name) > 4
```

Are these correct? They do not run for me. I am unsure if this is an error with my SQL or my code.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "not run" mean?  What database are you using?  Both your queries look fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not correct, but it's only a small, simple mistake. (same mistake in both).

You are counting the wrong column in the `having` clause.
Personally, I would go with the second option, only replace the `COUNT(s2.Name)` to `COUNT(s.Id)` - and if your database supports it, `COUNT(DISTINCT s.Id)` is even better:

```
SELECT s2.Name
FROM students s
JOIN students s2 
    ON s2.Id = s.MentorId
GROUP BY s2.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.Id) > 4
```

Comment: thank you! what would you count in the first query? why does the distinct help? since student ID's are all unique (except for in the mentorId column), wouldn't the query you wrote select nobody? That is the logic as to why I chose to count the name instead

Comment: I would count `s2.id` in the first query. Why does distinct help? well, I didn't know if your ids are unique or not, so...

Answer (score 0):

I would start with aggregation.  The students who are mentoring more than 4 students are given by:

```
select s.mentorid
from students s
group by s.mentorid
having count(*) > 4;
```

To get the full student record, you can then use `in`, `exists`, or `join`:

```
select s.*  -- or whatever columns you like
from students s join
     (select s.mentorid
      from students s
      group by s.mentorid
      having count(*) > 4
     ) m
     on s.id = m.mentorid;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You were grouping by `s2.name` having a number of `s2.name` greater than `4`. You never use the same field for grouping and the aggregate function. What you really want here is grouping by `s2.name` having a number of `s.name` (you want to count the corresponding students for each mentor mentor : `GROUP BY mentor HAVING COUNT students > 4`)
2. You should infact use `s.id` because otherwise it will not work if you have several students with the same name

```sql
SELECT s2.Name
FROM students s
JOIN students s2 ON s2.Id = s.MentorId
GROUP BY s2.Name
HAVING COUNT(s.id) > 4
```

Tested and it works :)